# Magic methods in static objects

Tags: php, oop, session, static-methods

I am trying to achieve this. I have session manager class, its something I developed for my framework. I need to have unique session keys, so instead of doing something like this:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = $bar;
```

I do this:

```
Session::set('foo',$bar);
```

and the set function will do something like this:

```
$_SESSION[$unique.'foo'] = $bar;
```

Its nice, it works, but I would like to use it like this:

```
Session['foo'] = $bar
```

or like this:

```
Session->foo = $bar
```

I found that I cant use -> in static objects, and I also cant use magic functions like __set and __get. So, is there any way how can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your session class a singleton?

```
class Session
{
   public static $instance;

   public static function init()
   {
        self::$instance = new Session();
   }    

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
echo(Session::$instance->foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use __call then

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

But `Session['foo'] = $bar` is impossible to use.

Comment: "Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods will not be triggered in static context."

Comment: any chance you refer to __callStatic?

Comment: @Hasan Khan oops, my fault. Then he has to use singleton as you have said before.